# Find Residue of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ when $f(z) = z^2-2z+3$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working through some examples in Lang's Complex Analysis 3rd Edition and cannot seem to understand how they come to this conclusion on how to find the residues of this problem. I have attached a screenshot. [image: HERE]
It is about finding the residues of $1/f(z)$ when $f(z) = z^2 -2z + 3$

Comment: I'm sorry but what you don't understand? If what Lang is saying does not make sense, then you need to read again the chapter or find a different reference because it is hard to explain better than he already did.

Answer (score 0):

So, the Residues are defined as the term of $\displaystyle z^{-1}$ in the Laurent Expansion near a pole.

You know that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{z^2-2z-3}=\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-3)}$, which has poles at $z=-1$ and $z=3$.

Let's say that near $f(z)$ can be written, near $z=-1$, as $...a_2(z+1)^2+a_1(z+1)+a_0+a_{-1}(z+1)^{-1}$. It doesn't go beyond $-1$ since we know the order of the pole.

Since we care about the coefficient $a_{-1}$, we can just find the limit of $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 1}(z+1)f(z)$, since every other term will go to $0$.

This coefficient $a_{-1}$ is the residue of $f(z)$ near $z=1$.

In this case, $\displaystyle \text{Res}(f;-1)=\lim_{z \to 1}\frac{z+1}{(z+1)(z-3)}=-\frac{1}{2}$, and $\displaystyle \text{Res}(f;3)=\lim_{z \to 3}\frac{z-3}{(z+1)(z-3)}=\frac{1}{4}$.

### -

I actually made a very big error. I misread the function as $z^2-2z-3$. However, the logic here still holds. I'll keep it up since it's a good example.

Just factor $\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{z^2-2z+3}=\frac{1}{(z-1-i\sqrt{2})(z-1+i\sqrt{2})}$

Is this hint sufficient?

And by the way, the integral is $-2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues. Negative because the integral is taken clockwise.

Comment: haha yeah! i was wondering if that example was good enough? do you want me to solve use your actual function? it won't take long

Comment: I understand how you got to the 1/(z-pole1)(z- pole2) step but it is unclear to me how the residue is then 1/(pole1 - pole2)

Comment: i never memorized that formula, but it isn't 1/(pole1-pole2) in general! it's just that you have first order poles. do you understand the way i got that from the laurent expansion?

Comment: Maybe I just dont understand the intuition behind the residue of a function, can you see the residue just by looking at the function in this case or is there further work to be done to get to that conclusion that the book found?

Comment: There is no mention of that sort of formula in the rest of the chapter of the Lang book :-(

Comment: well, i'll give a different example. for the function $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^2}$, the residue is zero. because the coefficient of the term $z^{-1}$ in the laurent expansion is zero

Comment: The formula for residue is $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}((z-z_0)^nf(z)))$

Comment: Thank you alot for this help! I just need to work on immediately expanding my functions into Laurent to see the coefficients more often. This makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Where n is the order of the pole. In this case, you have a first order pole, so it's just $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z) $

Comment: Be careful though since we are talking about the residue of 1/f(z) in this case so wouldnt you multiply the limit by 1/f(z)?

Comment: But you don't have to expand into Laurent every time! This demo was just so you can feel confident using this formula, because it comes right from the Laurent expansion :)

Comment: @EmilyChristiansen GREAT catch! yes, it would be 1/f(z). i'm used to taking residues of f(z), but yes, you know what i mean

Comment: Sorry! Just one more thing, can you explain to me why every term of the Laurent series goes to zero when you take the limit? @Saketh

Comment: so consider 4(z-1)^3+  2(z-1)^2 + (z-1) + 5. when you take the limit as z goes to 1, you just have 4(0)^3 + 2(0)^3 + 0 + 5 the only term that doesn't go to zero is that constant term. you want to take advantage of that

Comment: especially when it's hard to express the function in laurent series form easily, like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin(z)}$.